# Hibernate: Referencing multiple tables through a single join table

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Say I have some table `A` each of which has many `B`'s each of which has many `C`'s and so on for however many levels.

Now there is also some table `X` which is positioned at some level in this hierarchy (e.g. a particular `X` is associated with a `B` and thus also an `A`, but not a `C` or a `D`).

I am trying to maintain this relationship via a join table, call it `hierarchy_mapping`, which has columns: `a_id`, `b_id`, `c_id`, and so on where all but one are not null and insertions into `X` always also inserts into `hierarchy_mapping`, given an existing `a_id`, `b_id`, or `c_id`.

First of all, is this is a proper way to model such a hierarchy where `X` can be inserted at any level of this hierarchy?

Secondly, obviously, my implementation below doesn't work with Hibernate and I'm not entirely sure why. It works fine when the entity definition for `X` only references one of `A`, `B`, or `C` via the join table `hierarchy_mapping` (i.e. if I removed the member variables `b` and `c` from the POJO definition below):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class X {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "x_id")
    private Integer xId;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "hierarchy_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "x_id", referencedColumnName = "x_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
    )
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private A a;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "hierarchy_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "x_id", referencedColumnName = "x_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id")
    )
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "hierarchy_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "x_id", referencedColumnName = "x_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "c_id")
    )
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private C c;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I see that with my implementation above, when I query for a single `X` via a `JpaRepository` implementation, Hibernate performs a left outer join as such:

`SELECT x.x_id, x.name, .., m.b_id FROM TABLE_X x LEFT OUTER JOIN hierarchy_mapping m ON x.x_id = m.x_id WHERE x.name = ?`

To note is that it for some reason it only selects `b_id` from `hierarchy_mapping` and doesn't also select `a_id` and `c_id` as well. Then the most important thing is that Hibernate is not performing a subsequent query like it normally does to get the information from the `B` table for the row associated with `b_id` so that it could populate that member variable `b` in the instance of `X` that is returned. (e.g. a subsequent query like `SELECT b.b_id, b.description, .. FROM TABLE_B b where b._id = ?`)

Why are both of these happening?

Comment: Are you hoping that you can avoid adding the field `X` to each entity `A,B ... Z`? Is the `@JoinTable` thing an effort to accomplish that? Is it enougt that it is UNIDIRECTIONAL so `X` has `A,B ... Z`?

Comment: Yes I want the relationship in `X` and not in every `A, B, ...` for cleanliness and also because the `A, B, ..` tables will not have very many insertions but `X` certainly will, so I want the relationships formed when persisting an `X`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not telling what is the best way to accomplish what you are trying since the actual problem you are trying to solve is not clear at all.

This solution is based on assumption that with this `X` you just want to attach some generic data to any of `A,B ... Z`

Looking at your code I would suggest you to consider JPA inheritance to have this working and to have code more clear and manageable (well, at least in my opinion).

Create a base entity that `A,B ... Z` inherit.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) // needs to be joined to work
public class Alphabet {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   // X is here to have relationship bi-directional
   // leave it out if not needed
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="alphabet", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) 
   @Setter
   private X x;
}
```

Then let every entity in  `A,B ... Z` to inherit this  and make the needed other relationships, for example `A` & `B`

**Entity A**

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class A extends Alphabet {   
   private Character character = 'A'; // just some field, add the needed fields

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="a")
   private Collection<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Entity B**

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class B extends Alphabet {
   private Character character = 'B';

   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @Setter
   private A a;
```

}

Then simply :

**Entity X**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hierarchy_mapping")
@Getter
public class X {

   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @Setter
   private Alphabet alphabet;

   // and possible other data you want to add in your `X`
}
```

**Example :**

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
a.getBs().add(b);   

X xa = new X(), xb = new X();

xa.setAlphabet(a);
a.setX(xa); 

xb.setAlphabet(b);
b.setX(xb);

em.persist(a);
```

When **setting** the alphabet there is no need to think if it is `A`, `D` or `Q`. Just `setAlphabet(..)`

When **getting** the alphabet you could create a utility method to X like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getAlphabet(Class<T> classT) {
    Alphabet at = getAlphabet();
    if(null!=at && classT.isAssignableFrom(at.getClass()))
        return (T)at;
    return null;
}
```

Above method can be used like

```
B b = x.getAlphabet(B.class);
```

You anyway need to know what you are digging from `X`. And if it does not exist you will get `null` instead.

Comment: Well the problem with inheritance is that some of my alphabet tables don't have similar attributes and I would like to reference those through an `X` instance. I don't think a bunch of if-else's on `x.getAlphabet.getClass()` is going to work or be the proper way to approach this.

Comment: Also do you know why my original solution/definition of the class `X` doesn't work? Not why you wouldn't suggest, but why it simply doesn't fetch the `A, B, ..` instances when I fetch or persist an `X`? (Eager/lazy fetching aside because that doesn't seem to make a difference)

Comment: @rawa For the second comment, honestly I have never seen / analyzed such approach I mean this `@Jointable` annotation multiplied with every `A,B ... Z` field so cannot tell easily... For the first comment: can you provide in your question - even partially pseudo - code of the case where you fetch `X`s and reference `A,B ... Z`?

Comment: The case is trivial, it's as simple as `xRepository.findOne(..)` and then simply accessing one of the alphabet instances via `x.getA()` or `x.getB()`. On the persistence side, simply: `x.setA(..)` before calling `xRepository.save(x)`. `xRepository` is an instance of a `JpaRepository` in my Spring Boot application.

Comment: I did edit my original post to provide clarity on the unexpected behavior Hibernate is performing

Comment: @rawa I updated my alternative solution to show that in this scenario - as i understand it - there is no need for any mass `if...else..` blocks.